# Prove $\frac{d}{dx}{\rm arctanh}(\ln \cosh x) = \frac{\tanh x}{1-(\ln \cosh x)^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, self-learning

In the book "Lehrbuch der Analysis Teil I" of Heuser page 303, there was a task: Prove
$$\frac{d}{dx}{\rm arctanh}(\ln \cosh x) = \frac{\tanh x}{1-(\ln \cosh x)^2}.$$
When I tried, I ended up with
$$\frac{d}{dx}{\rm arctanh}(\ln \cosh x) = \tanh x \frac 1 2 \frac{1+\ln \cosh x}{1-\ln \cosh x},$$
from which it should be able to say
$$\frac 1{1-(\ln \cosh x)^2} = \frac 1 2 \frac{1+\ln \cosh x}{1-\ln \cosh x}.$$
How should it lead to the proof? I made already mistake at the earlier step?

Comment: why dt? is it x=x(t)?

Comment: @Mosk True. I was probably tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ \frac{d}{dx}{\rm arctanh[f(x)]}=\frac{f'(x)}{1-[f(x)]^2}$$

So you have:
$$\ \frac{d}{dx}{\rm arctanh}(\ln(\cosh(x)))=(\ln(\cosh(x)))'\cdot\frac{1}{1-[\ln(\cosh(x))]^2}=$$
$$\ =\frac{\tanh(x)}{1-[\ln(\cosh(x))]^2}$$

I do not understand how you get your result

Comment: Close to the problem in the book, I saw $\arctan x = \frac 1 2 \ln \frac {1 + x}{1 - x}$. I took it wrong that the left side of the equation was $(\arctan x)'$. Sorry, this was careless, but it was true that I struggled with this problem because of this misunderstanding.